# Python's Numpy dot function returning incorrect value, why?

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

Real simple, my code is:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([0.4, 0.3])
b = np.array([-0.15, 0.2])

print(np.dot(a,b))
```

The dot product of this should be 0, and instead i get:

```
3.3306690738754695e-18
```

Comment: So a number that would be *rounded-off* to 0...

Comment: The number shouldn't even be a number to round to begin with.  0.4 * -0.15 = -0.6
0.3 * 0.2 = 0.6.  Add them together, 0.

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi how, precisely, do you imagine a floating-point binary representation of that number would work? For example, how would it represent `0.15`, again, recall, it is fundamentally a binary representation

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I shouldn't have to imagine it?  If i can easily do these operations in R studio and Matlab without having to preface-declare my variables, i'd safely assume that something like numpy could do the same.

Comment: @ProximusSeraphimDimitriDavi matlab and R work in exactly the same way. Again, *how do you imagine they work*? Look, if you are tryinh to do any sort of scientific/numerical computing, you **must** understand floating point numbers and their inherent limitations

Comment: Although note, for this *particular* case, I cannot reproduce your output

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I ran this first via matlab, R studio, and online dot product calculators all giving back 0.

Comment: Again, I'm actually getting 0 as well in Python. Are you sure this is a [mcve]?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes sir, i have it in 2 different scripts just to make sure and it gives back that exact answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating-point!

Floating-point (i.e. non-integer) arithmetic tends not to be 100% accurate.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) for more info.

Also, note that your result is very close to zero.

Comment: So i tried defining it this way as well:
a = np.array([0.4, 0.3], float)
b = np.array([-0.15, 0.2],float)

IS there a way to define it so that it gives back the answer, or do i just use a round math function?

Comment: a) You can try to use integers instead. E.g. if you know the values are always going to be on 2 decimals, you shift them:
 a = np.array([40, 30]) b = np.array([-15, -20])

However, this can backfire quickly, if you try to make multiple operations chained one after the other.

b) You have to do some rounding. You can e.g. round the answers on 10**(-15) to get a result that is accurate enough. This is the usual way to deal with floating-point.

Comment: rather than do that i just used the answer that was accepted and do a quick for loop/zip and increment